# Recording screen on openSUSE Tumbleweed leads to black screen

Tags: opensuse, recording

I want to record my screen in openSUSE Tumbleweed, but it always fails. I've tried four recorders (listed below), but my video always results in a black video. The only thing that can be seen is the cursor. Does anyone know what is going on? Recorder apps tried:

[recordmydesktop](http://recordmydesktop.sourceforge.net/about.php) (from openSUSE's wiki guide)
[simplescreenrecorder](https://www.maartenbaert.be/simplescreenrecorder/)
[ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop)
[vokoscreen](http://linuxecke.volkoh.de/vokoscreen/vokoscreen.html)

Comment: Which openSUSE release are you using? Which tools have you tried?

Comment: I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed, hence the latest release. The tools I've tried are: recordmydesktop (from openSUSE's wiki guide), simplescreenrecorder, ffmpeg and vokoscreen.

Comment: I've never used Tumbleweed, I use Leap. Maybe you should post your question in https://forums.opensuse.org, there are probably more people around who use openSUSE, and they are pretty responsive there.

Comment: Thanks for the info! :)